# Combine dictionary from a loop update statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

this is my current code

```
import copy
modes = ['dry', 'cool', 'heat']
result = {}

result['definition'] = [{'dtype': '', 'label': '', 'value': ''}]
    for mode in modes:
    for i in result['definition']:
        for mode in modes:
            ii = copy.deepcopy(i)
            ii.update(dict(dtype='mode', label=mode, value=0))
            print ii
```

This is my result

```
{'dtype': 'mode', 'value': 0, 'label': 'dry'}
{'dtype': 'mode', 'value': 0, 'label': 'cool'}
{'dtype': 'mode', 'value': 0, 'label': 'heat'}
```

I want to my output to look like this

```
result['definition'] = [{'dtype': 'mode', 'label': 'dry', 'value': 0}, 
                        {'dtype': 'mode', 'label': 'cool', 'value': 0}, 
                        {'dtype': 'mode', 'label': 'heat', 'value': 0}]
```

Could you please give me suggestion to this? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: The output of your code is different to the output you have printed in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import copy
modes = ['dry', 'cool', 'heat']
result = {}

result['definition'] = [{'dtype': '', 'label': '', 'value': ''}]

result1 = dict()
result1 = {'definition':[]}
for i in result['definition']:
  for mode in modes:
    ii = copy.deepcopy(i)
    ii.update(dict(dtype='mode', label=mode, value=0))
    result1['definition'].append(ii)
print (result1['definition'])
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. I find it helpful but it iterates on how many inputs i put on modes.

Comment: you can get rid of first for loop, its unnecessary, i'll update answer as well